# SQL Cross Join The multi-part identifier "xxxx" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, cross-join

I'm working on replacing cursors with Cross Joins where I can in our system. I have the following that is a combo of old and new code (isn't everything?..)

```
SELECT IWC.[ItemId], LEFT(LEFT(IWC.[Title],100 - LEN(ISNULL(SI.StyleInfo,N''))) + ISNULL(SI.[StyleInfo],'|'),100)
        FROM #custom_ImportWebContent IWC 
        Left JOIN
            (SELECT SL.[ItemId],
                ' | ' +
                CASE
                    WHEN SL.[Level1Name] = 'Color' THEN SL.[Level1Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level2Name] = 'Color' THEN SL.[Level2Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level3Name] = 'Color' THEN SL.[Level3Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level4Name] = 'Color' THEN SL.[Level4Description] END + ' | ' +
                CASE
                    WHEN SL.[Level1Name] = 'Size' THEN SL.[Level1Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level2Name] = 'Size' THEN SL.[Level2Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level3Name] = 'Size' THEN SL.[Level3Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level4Name] = 'Size' THEN SL.[Level4Description] END + ' | ' +
                CASE
                    WHEN SL.[Level1Name] = 'Dimension' THEN SL.[Level1Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level2Name] = 'Dimension' THEN SL.[Level2Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level3Name] = 'Dimension' THEN SL.[Level3Description]
                    WHEN SL.[Level4Name] = 'Dimension' THEN SL.[Level4Description] END AS [StyleInfo]
            FROM [StyleLevels] SL) SI ON SI.[ItemId] = IWC.[ItemId]
    CROSS JOIN dbo.GetItems(IWC.[ItemId], IWC.[Title], N'Admin')<-- error-The multi-part identifier "IWC.ItemId" could not be bound. Also for IWC.Title
    ORDER BY IWC.[RowNum]
```

I'm out of scope here aren't I? How would I circumvent this and pass those values to the TVF?

Do I need to do something like create a derived table from the LEFT JOIN first and then CROSS JOIN on that derived table?

Comment: try changing "Cross Join" to "Cross Apply"

Comment: Yes, the error went away, thanks.  Now, to check is semantically it is working as expected